# How to change image style using hook_views_pre_render()

Tags: views, 8, hooks, media

I am trying to adapt the following Drupal 7 code to Drupal 8, in order to set a different image style to every image in a view:

```
// Assigns a random style name to each image
function <MODULE_NAME>_views_pre_render(&$view)
{    
  if($view->name == 'SOME VIEW') 
  {
    $styles = array('thumbnail', 'medium', 'large');
    foreach($view->result as &$result) 
    { 
      $result->field_field_image[0]['rendered']['#image_style'] = $styles[array_rand($styles)];        
    } 
  }
}
```

Right now I have:

```
function <MODULE_NAME>_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view)
{    
  if($view->id() == 'SOME VIEW') 
  {
    $styles = array('thumbnail', 'medium', 'large');
    foreach($view->result as &$result) 
    { 
      $image = $result->_entity->get("field_media_image");
      $image->SOME_FUNCTION('#style_name') = $styles[array_rand($styles)];        
    } 
  }
}
```

However, I can't figure out what SOME_FUNCTION would be -- There does not appear to be any way to access the render array from an ImageItem object.

Answer (score 2):

I gave up on `hook_views_pre_render` and wound up meeting my requirements with `template_preprocess_image_formatter` as follows:

```
function <TEMPLATE_NAME>_preprocess_image_formatter(&$variables) {
  $styles = array('thumbnail', 'medium', 'large');
  if ($variables['image']['#style_name'] === 'medium') {
    $variables['image']['#style_name'] = $styles[array_rand($styles)];
  }
}
```